# At what point in his narrative does the prophet Yona appear to die?

Tags: matthew, jonah

Christ essentially appealed to Yona being dead three days and three nights in the heart of the sea as proof that he too would be dead three days and three nights in the heart of the earth (i.e., the sign of Yona = [Matthew 12:38-40](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2012%3A38-40%3B&version=NASB;SBLGNT)).

At what point in his narrative does the prophet Yona [Jonah] appear to die?